# How can I calculate the remaining balance of a customer in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

**Info**: I am trying to make an app like a monthly instalment. When I create a file of Customer. The price of the `Property` purchased will be added to the `Customer` remaining balance automatically. My app logic is multiple payments for a single customer. I want to add all payments amount in `collec_amount` and collect_amount will be deducted from the remaining balance. If I delete any payment object from a customer then the remaining balance will be automatically updated before deleting the object.

**Problem**: The code below calculation is not working properly. The calculation creates a mess when I try to update the existing payment. If anybody has a better solution to the reported post. I would be grateful for any help.

**models.py**

```
class Property(models.Model):
    area = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    prop_select = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    remaining = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    collect_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.remaining = self.prop_select.price
        self.remaining -= self.collect_amount
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Payment(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, related_name='payment')
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.customer.collect_amount += self.amount
        self.customer.save()
        super(Payment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.customer.collect_amount -= self.amount
        self.customer.save()
        super(Payment, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: what is the "mess" you are talking about? Can you be more specific?

Comment: when i create a payment of **1000** out of **4000** for a customer.  if i try to edit the exiting payment i want only that to updated particularly i don't want any changes in remaining balance. henceforth  after i complete the updating exiting payment then the remaining balance can get updated it self.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator
from django.db.models import Sum


class Property(models.Model):
    area = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=2, default=0.0,
                            validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])


class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    prop_select = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    remaining = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=2, default=0.0,
                        validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])
    collect_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=2, default=0.0,
                        validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])

    def get_remaning_amount(self):
        property_price = self.prop_select.price
        payment_done_by_customer = Payment.objects.filter(customer=self).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum']
        return property_price - payment_done_by_customer


class Payment(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, related_name='payment')
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=17, decimal_places=2, default=0.0,
                        validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])
```

Comment: let me know if you able to get this code?

Comment: Dear i am not able to upvote your solution because upvote button is not showing me...